# session maintain of my own login in openinviter

Tags: php, session

I m using OpenInviter for fetching Email Addresses from different Service provider like gmail, yahoo etc. I am not be able to maintain session on the pages where i m using the open source of OpenInviter. if i try to maintain the session of my login user it display nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if OpenInviter is overwriting your session or keys inside your session. Does the issue still occur if you make these changes?

- change your session identifier or
- change the key you are using to store the user id in the session

Finally, does the session of your user return if you navigate to a page that doesn't include the OpenInviter code?

Sorry to answer your question with a question, but I think some more information will help everyone to understand the issue better.